# Number of $n$-permutations for which ${\tau}^k = id$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, permutations

I am curious about the formula(any closed form) for the number of $n$-permutations $\tau$ such that ${\tau}^{n-1} = id$. How about for the case ${\tau}^n = id$ ?

Comment: If $n$ is prime, there should be $(n-1)!+1$ of the form $\tau^n=\text{id}$, is that correct?

Comment: The [OEIS entry A074759](https://oeis.org/A074759) is relevant. It was found with the exponential generating function $$n! [z^n]\exp\left(\sum_{d|n} \frac{z^d}{d}\right).$$

Comment: You are right. I mean, a general formula. I know the first few numbers from A008307(OEIS), where diagonal elements are those.

Comment: Differentiate the generating function to obtain a recurrence relation.

Comment: What is the generating function for that?

Comment: egf for the sequence $a_n = n![z^n]exp(...)$

Comment: @Marko Are you sure that differentiating is helpful here? The sum in the generating function depends on $n$ (and the divisors of $n$), so the desired value cannot (obviously) be expressed as $f^{(n)}(0)$ for some known $f$.

Comment: I understand it.  Thanks!

Comment: This problem appeared by way of a question that I didn't understand properly at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785015/).

Comment: So the answer for the first question is $$n! [z^n]\exp\left(\sum_{d|(n-1)} \frac{z^d}{d}\right)?$$